# How to show values on ASP.NET Chart

Tags: asp.net, mschart

Here is my chart:
[image]

ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="752px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Column2" YValueMembers="Column1">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="DarkGray">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

How can I show values on blue boxes?

Comment: I would highly recommend you download the excellent sample application from http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418 - this will answer this and many other questions about the chart controls.

Comment: I will have a look @Joe. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this from your codebehind:

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

You can also do this from your ASPX code:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="752px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Column2" YValueMembers="Column1" IsValueShownAsLabel="true">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="DarkGray">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```